# Conditional binding with AngularJS, concatenate and bind value if property is not empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am new to Angular and am trying to bind a string to a model if the value !== empty. This work for one input, but I would like to combine multiple text inputs into one string.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.source">
<input type="text" ng-model="data.medium">     

<span ng-show="data.source"><h3>{{'additionToSource' + data.source}}</h3></span>
<span ng-show="data.medium"><h3>{{'additionToMedium' + data.medium}}</h3>
```

Comment: Using ng-show and ng-hide are probably what you want in this case.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/AYOrofo/3/edit)**

You could simply add the `ng-show` or `ng-hide` directive to the `h3` itself if you are wanting to hide the whole element.

Alternatively, you could use ternary in the binding to determine what is bound:

```
{{foo ? 'some string '+foo : ''}}
```

Explanation:

```
foo //if $scope.foo is truthy (not empty)
? 'some string '+foo //bind a string with $scope.foo concatenated to the end
: '' //otherwise, bind in an empty string
```

For your code, it would be:

```
<h3>{{data.source ? 'additionToString' + data.source : ''}}</h3>
```

Based on your comments, you may also be looking to return a binding with a function: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/AYOrofo/5/edit)**

```
<input ng-model="foo">

<h3 ng-show="foo">{{bar()}}</h3>
<h3>{{foo ? bar() : ''}}</h3>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.foo = '';
$scope.bar = function() {
  return 'added value '+$scope.foo;
};
```

Comment: How could I bind that <h3> to an additional <h3>. Would I create another model inside the <h3>?

Comment: @CoreyRab you should update your question to be more clear...I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean something like this? http://jsbin.com/AYOrofo/5/edit I just use a function to return the formatted string.